# Owfs.js doesn't see fake device

Tags: node.js, 1wire

I’m trying to run owfs on my local with fake devices (from owfs.conf) , but have troubles with it. This is my code, which prints empty array

```
var OwfsClient =  require('owfs').Client;
var owfs = new OwfsClient('127.0.0.1', '4304');

owfs.dir("/",function(err, directories){
    console.log(directories);
})
```

And it return nothing. In the same time when I do owdir from console I’m getting this

```
$ owdir
/3A.67C6697351FF
/3A.4AEC29CDBAAB
/3A.F2FBE3467CC2
/3A.54F81BE8E78D
/10.765A2E63339F
/05.C99A66320DB7
/bus.1
/bus.0
/uncached
/settings
/system
/statistics
/structure
```

Then I’m trying to read device like this

```
owfs.read("/10.765A2E63339F", function (err, data){
    console.log(err, data);
})
```

and it outputs

```
{ msg: 'Communication Error. Received -1',
  header: 
   { version: 0,
     payload: 0,
     ret: -1,
     controlflags: 32,
     size: 0,
     offset: 0 },
  options: 
   { path: '/10.67C6697351FF',
     command: 2,
     server: '127.0.0.1',
     port: '4304' } }

undefined
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup only owfs?
You MUST setup also OWserver

Default: `owserver --w1 -p4304`

More you can find here:

> http://owfs.org/index.php?page=owserver

Sometimes you're also need this - `ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1`

Also update if not.  works only nodejs srv <= 0.12.8

> https://github.com/benediktarnold/owfs